# How Can I Stop My Camera From Rotating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, raycasting, mouse-position

I made the precursor to my 3d Agario game. It is a mouse-oriented game. You use the mouse to control most of the movement. This includes the rotation of the Camera.

My problem is the Camera won't stop rotating. This is because it is very hard to center the mouse to the center of the screen, and the way I made the Camera rotate is by using a Sine equation.

Here is my code:

```
//public
public GameObject player;
public float rotationSpeed;

//v3
private Vector3 mousePos;
private Vector3 playerPos;
private Vector3 camPos;

//float
private float sideX;
private float sideZ;
private float sideC;
private float camX;
private float camZ;
private float camC;
private float rotX;
private float rotZ;
private float rotC;
private float rotAngle;
private Quaternion currRotation;

//camera
private Camera hitCam;

void Start ()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(30, 0, 0);
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, 15, 0);
}
void LateUpdate ()
{
    mousePos = HitCameraController.mousePos;
    playerPos = player.transform.position;

    sideX = (mousePos.x - playerPos.x);
    sideZ = (mousePos.z - playerPos.z);
    sideC = (Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(sideX, 2) + Mathf.Pow(sideZ, 2)));

    camC = 15;
    camX = (camC * sideX) / sideC;
    camZ = (camC * sideZ) / sideC;

    rotX = (sideX + camX);
    rotZ = (sideZ + camZ);
    rotC = (Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(rotX, 2) + Mathf.Pow(rotZ, 2)));

    if (rotX >= 0 && rotZ >= 0)
    {
        rotAngle = (Mathf.Asin(rotX / rotC) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    }
    if (rotX >= 0 && rotZ <= 0)
    {
        rotAngle = 180 - (Mathf.Asin(rotX / rotC) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    }
    if (rotX <= 0 && rotZ >= 0)
    {
        rotAngle = (Mathf.Asin(rotX / rotC) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    }
    if (rotX <= 0 && rotZ <= 0)
    {
        rotAngle = -180 - (Mathf.Asin(rotX / rotC) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    }
    camPos = new Vector3((playerPos.x - camX), 15, (playerPos.z - camZ));
    currRotation = Quaternion.Euler(30, rotAngle, 0);

    // Move Camera
    transform.position = camPos;

    // Rotate Camera

    /*transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
        transform.rotation, currRotation, 
        (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime));*/

    transform.rotation = currRotation;
}
```

I want to make a sort of "safe-zone" that will prevent the calculation of the rotating angle. For instance, if I keep my mouse within a certain boundary in the center, the Camera won't rotate.

I tried to make the boundary using an "or" statement, but it didn't give me the result I was looking for (the camera would still rotate even when my mouse was in the boundary. The Camera would stop on some tries, but it would jitter immensely before doing so.)

I know exactly why this is occurring: the ray isn't being cast on a still camera; hence, the mouse coordinate will always change, even if I don't move the mouse. I tried casting the ray to the "Hit" camera (the still Camera), but the follow camera couldn't pick up on the mouse movement. I don't know how to fix this problem other than to keep brainstorming for an intuitive solution, but my brain can only innovate so much.

If you could think of a solution before me, let me know by any means.

Answer (score 0):

```
[...]
void LateUpdate ()
{
    mousePos = HitCameraController.mousePos;
    playerPos = player.transform.position;

    sideX = (mousePos.x - playerPos.x);
    sideZ = (mousePos.z - playerPos.z);

    sideC = (Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(sideX, 2) + Mathf.Pow(sideZ, 2)));

    // New Stuff
    sideC -= 5f; // substract the safe-zone-radius
    if(sideC < 0f)
    {
        // Inside safe-zone, do nothing.
        sideC = 0f;
        sideX = 0f;
        sideZ = 0f;
    }else{
        // Outside safe-zone, correct values to avoid jumping.
        float x_ratio = sideX / sideZ; // be careful with "divide by zero"
        float z_ratio = sideZ / sideX;
        sideX -= 5 * x_ratio;
        sideZ -= 5 * z_ratio;
    }
    // End New Stuff

    camC = 15;
    camX = (camC * sideX) / sideC;
    camZ = (camC * sideZ) / sideC;

    rotX = (sideX + camX);
    rotZ = (sideZ + camZ);
    rotC = (Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(rotX, 2) + Mathf.Pow(rotZ, 2)));

    if (rotX >= 0 && rotZ >= 0)
    {
        rotAngle = (Mathf.Asin(rotX / rotC) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    }
    if (rotX >= 0 && rotZ <= 0)
    {
        rotAngle = 180 - (Mathf.Asin(rotX / rotC) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    }
    if (rotX <= 0 && rotZ >= 0)
    {
        rotAngle = (Mathf.Asin(rotX / rotC) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    }
    if (rotX <= 0 && rotZ <= 0)
    {
        rotAngle = -180 - (Mathf.Asin(rotX / rotC) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    }

    camPos = new Vector3((playerPos.x - camX), 15, (playerPos.z - camZ));
    currRotation = Quaternion.Euler(30, rotAngle, 0);
```

Comment: The player is center but the problem is sideC will never be less than 0 because it's a sqrt. And I want the safe-zone to be 5 units from the center of the camera in both directions.

Comment: Of course, I missed the sqrt. Then you don't even need the if-else. 
Just substract 5 (maybe you need to substract 5² ?) and check if it is `> 0`. Be sure to substract the same when doing rotation calculations, so you avoid the jumpiness when leaving safe-zone

Comment: Can you rewrite the answer?

Comment: I changed my answer

Comment: I letting you know that I quit further progress on this game and started making a new game. :/ This game is going to be way too complex to rationalize.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to avoid the reverse calculating with sine and cosine. Maybe you set a screen-space radius, so you only work with the mousePosition.